# Permission denied in chocolatey

Tags: chocolatey

I have choco installed in my Windows 10 PC. Now, I am trying to install Erlang and Elixir. When I am running the command `choco install erlang` or `choco install elixir`, I am getting the following error :

```
Installing the following packages:
erlang
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading erlang 22.0... 100%
erlang not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\erlang' is denied.
erlang package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
The install of erlang was NOT successful.
erlang not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\erlang' is denied.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - erlang (exited 1) - erlang not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\erlang' is denied.
```

From the message it is clear that the file is downloaded successfully, but the installation permission is denied. So what to do to fix this error?

Comment: Are you running Chocolatey from an administrative shell? If not, that is likely why you are seeing those errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have opened Command prompt as administrator and the installations continued without any error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default installation of Chocolatey installs to the programdata folder. As a result, any usage of Chocolatey needs to happen from an elevated, or administrative, shell.

If you open an administrative PowerShell or Command prompt window, and re-run the installation command, they should work as expected.

It is possible to do an an administrative installation of Chocolatey if that is what is required. Check:

https://chocolatey.org/install

For more information on options there.

Answer (score 21):

We need to open the power-shell as Admin. In windows right click run as Administrator [image].

Comment: Or we can make the shortcut [always run as an admin](https://superuser.com/questions/1153519/create-a-shortcut-to-always-run-as-administrator)

Answer (score 2):

Steps

1. First enable the hidden Windows 10 administrator account
   [image]

[image]

2.ensure that you are using an administrative shell
"In window 10 PowerShell already installed"
[image]

Now Run "Get-ExecutionPolicy". If it returns Restricted, then run Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned or Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process.

Now run the following command (security concerns kindly review https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1): copy in one time below command

> Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

3. Press Enter.
4. Wait a few seconds for the command to complete.
5. If you don't see any errors, you are ready to use Chocolatey! Type choco or choco -? now

Answer (score 0):

Before running cmd / powershell
Click run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

I got this error even after running as administrator, so tried giving folder rights to "everyone" and it worked.